# Synchronizing scores and achievements from Game Center to device?

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, gamekit

Just wondering on how frequently I should sync data from Game Center to the device? The first time the app is run, every time the app is run or once every x number of days?

I am trying to ensure that a user has the same achievements and high scores if he/she gets a new phone or deletes the app and re-installs it.

Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to guarantee the latest data, then you should try to update the data every time the app is run.

Answer (score 0):

If your sync process is scheduled to run in the background, you can even sync every time the data changes in addition to every time the app is launched.

If you are syncing just the deltas this should not be very expensive to do

my two cents ;)